# Join a MySQL table to itself + Operation

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I receive free updates for some forex currency pairs. I am trying to calculate the other pairs by deduction from those with anumerator and a denominator.

my MyQSL table (named param_forex):

[image]

my MySQL query

```
    UPDATE `param_forex` as pf
    JOIN `param_forex` as pf1 on pf1.numerator = pf.Ticker
    JOIN `param_forex` as pf2 on pf2.denominator = pf.Ticker
    SET pf.Rate = (SELECT pf1.`Rate` WHERE pf1.`Ticker`= pf1.numerator / SELECT pf2.`Rate` WHERE pf2.`Ticker`= pf2.denominator)
    WHERE pf.Source='Calc'
```

Result : 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0007 seconds.)
The expected output is for each line where the source is 'calc' to do the numerator divided by the denominator by fetching the appropriate values matching in the ticker columns and put the result in the rate column

I don't understand why it won't work, and I have spent hours on it.
(for those who have replied to a couple of my questions before, I hope you notice my queries are getting better...)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Your post is also missing the expected output.

Comment: I really don't see how I can give a good easy understandable description of the table without a screengrab. I am sorry I am lacking in imagination. And I have edited the question to explain the expected result

Comment: Why are you **arithmetically** dividing strings/varchars? Aren't you forgetting actually fetching those numerical values?

Comment: [How to make tables in good format in asking questions here (which is understandable by others)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda)

Comment: @JettoMartínez fair point. I have modified the query which still does not work

Comment: You don't need to imagine, you need to consult the links, read, understand, and update your post accordingly. If you don't visit those links, you'll never be able to know how to improve your post by guessing.

Comment: how are you running your query?  it is syntactically incorrect and will result in an error message.  for testing, you should run it in something that shows you errors.  I suggest the mysql command line client.

Comment: I am running it in the mysql command line client.

Comment: Turn your query intro a `SELECT` to see what is being calculated and where. I suggest you SELECT pf.forex_id, pf1.nominator, the subquery to get the rate from pf1, pf2.denominator, the subquery to get the rate from pf2 and the division you are trying to make. Don't forget your where clause, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the subquery, just use `pf1.Rate` and `pf2.Rate` directly in the `SET` clause.

You also have your `ON` conditions backwards, since `numerator` and `denominator` are only set in the rows with `Source = Calc`.

```
UPDATE `param_forex` as pf
JOIN `param_forex` as pf1 on pf.numerator = pf1.Ticker
JOIN `param_forex` as pf2 on pf.denominator = pf2.Ticker
SET pf.Rate = pf1.Rate / pf2.Rate
WHERE pf.Source='Calc'
```